# request not found error during post request

Tags: node.js, express

I have form with the following action

```
<form action="users/edit/profile/{{user._id}}" method="post">
```

route.js

```
router.post('/edit/profile/:id', controllers.updateUserProfile);
```

and in controller

```
updateUserProfile: function(req, res){
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email, first_name: req.body.first_name, last_name: req.body.last_name }}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.render("editProfile", {user: req.body});
            }
            res.redirect("/users/me/");
          });
    },
```

but when I submit the form I am getting 404 error 
[image: Error image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `router.post('/users/edit/profile/:id', controllers.updateUserProfile);
`

Comment: or it could be <form action="/edit/profile/{{user._id}}" method="post">